# How can I get an immutable version of an object from store.getState()?

Tags: react-redux, state, store, dispatch

I'm using react-redux for a project I'm working on. I noticed that when I grab an object from my store and edit it, the object in state changes without me dispatching the change (but doesn't trigger a re-render on the components attached to that reducer's object). How can I stop state from changing without a dispatch?

For example if I do:

```
    export function changeNeonGreenColourValue(colour) { 
        return (dispatch) => {
             var neonColours = store.getState().colours.neon; 
             neonColours.green = colour;
             dispatch(push('./home'));
        };
    }
```

And then in the layoutComponent I log:

```
console.log(this.props.state.colours.neon.green)
```

The output is still whatever I passed into changeNeonGreenColourValue() as "colour" but the page doesn't re-render to show that change. I know to get the page to re-render, all I have to do is dispatch the appropriate reducer case but I don't want the state object being altered at all unless I have an appropriate dispatch.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the 'standard' deep copying technique for solving this is to do a JSON stringifying and parse as so: `const copiedObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sourceObj));` Unfortunately if you use this on large objects that will need parsing frequently you're going to have performance issues in your app as I do, if anyone has any suggestions for this I welcome them.

edit: so both jQuery and Loadash have their own implementations of deep cloning that are supposed to be better performance-wise:
https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep

I personally implemented loadash to resolve my issue and it worked fine with little to no performance issues. I highly recommend it over JSON.stringify.